# Extend Meteor accounts-password to store multiple passwords

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am using the accounts-password package in my Meteor app.

I want to securely store user passwords for an external RESTful API that I will be accessing through HTTP basic access authentication (I'm aware of OAuth, but cannot use it in this case). These user passwords may differ from the passwords the users use to login to the Meteor app, so I need to store them separately.

Is it possible to extend accounts-password (or make use of its functions) to securely capture these external passwords from a user, store them against their user profile and make API calls from the server using them?

If not, how else can I achieve this simply and securely?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In looking through the code for accounts-password, I see that it hashes the passwords, which won't work for what I want as I have to be able to decrypt back to a string that can be sent as HTTP Basic Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

`users` is just a collection in the mongodb, thus you can store whatever you want to there and update it

```
Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$set:{
    'profile': {
        'service1': {
            username: name,
            password: hash-password
        }
    }
}});
```